# RESTORE VERIFYONLY locks file in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, restore

I'm using SQL Server 2012 SP2 to backup my transaction logs directly into Azure Blob Storage using the `BACKUP TO URL` statement.

I am then attemtpting to verify my transaction log as follows:

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM  URL = 'https://mystore.blob.core.windows.net/logfile.trn'
WITH CREDENTIAL = 'azurecreds'
```

The `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` operation puts a lease on the file in Azure which I can see using Azure Management Studio's blob browser (The last 2 I created without running RESTORE VERIFYONLY).

[image: Azure Management Studio]

I can manually break the lease using Azure Management Studio but am I doing something wrong with `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` that is leaving an active lease on the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems very similar to:

- [FIX: Cannot remove backup file after you restore the database from Windows Azure in SQL Server 2014 or SQL Server 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2970136)

From that Microsoft Support article:

> **Symptoms**
>
> Assume that you use the `RESTORE HEADERONLY` or `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` command to restore a database from Windows Azure Blob storage service in Microsoft SQL Server 2014 or SQL Server 2012. After the command is completed, you cannot remove the backup file.
>
> **Cause**
>
> The issue occurs because there is an infinite lease on the backup file. Some race conditions between internal threads cause the lease to be not released in some cases.

This is marked as first fixed in Cumulative Update 4 for SQL Server 2012 SP2. While the fix does not mention `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` explicitly, you should definitely check this out before reporting it as a bug.

The latest Service Pack for SQL Server 2012 at the time of writing is [SP3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49996), which will also include the fix mentioned above.

Finally, just to document something [GregGalloway](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/79569/greggalloway) originally left in a comment on the question, you can remove active leases using a script in the following MSDN article:

[Deleting Backup Blob Files with Active Leases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj919145.aspx)